# Process multiple arrays from form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

I am trying to process multiple arrays from a form, but I constantly face the issue where only the last field is submitted.

The form is echoing results (IP addresses and their rDNS settings) from an simple xml output and publishing these in an editable form and table.

```
<?php include_once("API.php");
$ips=array('xx.xx.xx.xx','xx.xx.xx.xx','xx.xx.xx.xx');

foreach($ips as $ip){
  $API->GetRdns($ip);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($API);
}

foreach ($xml->RdnsDetails as $RdnsDetails) :?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="hostname" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->hostname; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="extra" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->extra; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When the submit button is clicked, the changes have to be submitted.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    $API->Sent($ip,$_POST[hostname],$_POST[extra])    
  }
?>
```

How do I get the values 'hostname' and 'extra' submitted for each of the IP's ($ip)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating an array instead of a single value. Try this:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ip[<?php echo $ip; ?>]['hostname']" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->hostname; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ip[<?php echo $ip; ?>]['extra']" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->extra; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

You can catch this with:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  foreach ($_POST['ip'] as $ip => $info) {
    $API->Sent($value,$info['hostname'],$info['extra']);    
  }
?>
```

Comment: Getting further. However, it only processes the last IP entry.

Comment: Are you sure your `$ip` is different every rule? I don't know where you define it but maybe you need to change it to ` $RdnsDetails->ip`?

Comment: It is defined as $ips=array('xx.xx.xx.xx','xx.xx.xx.xx','xx.xx.xx.xx'); with foreach ($ips as $ip){}. I will edit my first post with the full relevant code. The RdnsDetails variable is ok.

Comment: You should place your `foreach ($xml->RdnsDetails as $RdnsDetails)` loop inside your `foreach($ips as $ip)` loop. I think that will do the job! And ofcourse use my example with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your submit button into a `<form>` to get the values

```
<form>
<?php foreach ($xml->RdnsDetails as $RdnsDetails) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="hostname" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->hostname; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="extra" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->extra; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Opslaan</button>
</form>
```

**another problem is you missed '' here:**

```
$API->Sent($value,$_POST['hostname'],$_POST['extra'])
```

Comment: The form was already in place (only copied the relevant elements above). Brackets make no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

a form by default will only send one value for each "name" entity in the form.  Can you try adding the brackets to the [name] property of the inputs so it sends the values as an array ?
I think i understand a little more now, you need the association between the IP and the hostname/extra values.  How about if you add the ip as a hidden form field

```
    <?php foreach ($xml->RdnsDetails as $RdnsDetails) :?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="ips[]" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hostname[]" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->hostname; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="extra[]" value="<?php echo $RdnsDetails->extra; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

then you can process in the backend something like this:

```
<?php
$ips = $_POST['ips']; 
$hostnames = $_POST['hostname']; 
$extras = $_POST['extras']; 
for($i=0;$i<count($ips);$i++) 
{
     echo "IP: " . $ips[i] . ", Hostname: " . $hostnames[i] . ", Extra: " . $extras[$i]; 
}
```

Comment: Tried to sent it as an array. Only problem facing here is that the output is "Array" when using $API->Sent($value,$_POST['hostname'],$_POST['extra'])

Comment: I dont think i have any idea what $API->Sent is supposed to be doing.  But the original question was for how to send multiple name:value pairs for a form and you do that by using arrays. That means you have to process it as an array in the backend.